# node express cookieSession cookies not being set

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api, cookie-session

A node express api for SPA with the following:

```
const express = require ('express');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const cookieSession = require ('cookie-session');
const cors = require ('cors');  

const app = express();
app.use (cors());

app.use (cookieSession({
  name: 'app',
  keys: ['a-key'],

  maxAge: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // 7 days
}));

const router = express.Router();
app.use ('/api', router);

router.use ('/login', login);
router.use ('/logout', logout);
router.use ('/users', users);
etc ...

app.listen (port);
```

Requests from the SPA are made using `fetch`:

```
try {
  await fetch ('/api/users');
  ... etc
}
```

Express runs on `localhost:3000` at the mo´, the dev SPA on `localhost:5000`.

A cookie is not being set in the browser; and `console.log` of `req.session` shows an empty `{}` object.

I have tried:

```
credentials: true,
origin: 'http://localhost:5000'
```

in the `cors` initiation

I have also tried:

```
secure: false,
httpOnly: false,
sameSite: false
```

in the `cookieSession` initiation

I have also tried including:

```
credentials: 'include'
```

on the `fetch` requests

None of this has worked, either alone, or all together.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the

```
fetch (url, {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

in the SPA is in fact needed, and once I had logged out and in again, the session was set correctly in the browser.